# Como fazer WHERE transformando coluna String em Data?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Estou usando o Grafana para consultar dados do PostgreSQL para criação de dashboards, a coluna fat_real é uma coluna com datas, porém está no formato String, preciso passar ela para o formato de data, essa parte deu certo, porém no grafana preciso usar o $__timeFilter para relacionar com o filtro padrão da aplicação, tentei fazer desta maneira:
*coluna planejamento é uma coluna float

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(fat_real, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::date) as data_real, sum(planejamento)
FROM rel
WHERE $__timeFilter(TO_DATE(fat_real, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::date)
GROUP BY data_real
```

mas o seguinte erro aparece "operator does not exist: character varying <= date"

Já tentei também:

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(fat_real, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::date) as data_real, sum(planejamento)
FROM rel
WHERE $__timeFilter(data_real::date)
GROUP BY data_real
```

mas o seguinte erro aparece:
column "data_real" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Tenta:

```
SELECT CAST(fat_real as DATE) as data_real, sum(planejamento)
FROM rel
WHERE $__timeFilter(data_real::date)
GROUP BY data_real
```

Se precisar da hora:

```
Troque DATE por TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Deu certo, mto obrigada